# Error installing RedCloth on Rails 3.0.3 and RVM on Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redcloth

I'm trying to add Redcloth to my Gem file, and when I run 'bundle install', I get the following:

```
Installing RedCloth (4.2.6) with native extensions /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:529:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

        /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/ruby extconf.rb 

Gem files will remain installed in /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@vendorguide/gems/RedCloth-4.2.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@vendorguide/gems/RedCloth-4.2.6/ext/redcloth_scan/gem_make.out
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:507:in `block in build_extensions'
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:482:in `each'
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:482:in `build_extensions'
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:156:in `install'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@vendorguide/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/source.rb:96:in `install'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@vendorguide/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:55:in `block in run'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@vendorguide/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `block in each'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@vendorguide/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@vendorguide/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@vendorguide/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:44:in `run'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@vendorguide/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@vendorguide/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/cli.rb:226:in `install'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@vendorguide/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@vendorguide/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@vendorguide/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@vendorguide/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@vendorguide/gems/bundler-1.0.10/bin/bundle:13:in `'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@vendorguide/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@vendorguide/bin/bundle:19:in `'
```

If I run "gem install RedCloth" and then run "bundle install", it works, however when I actually try to use RedCloth in a model 'Vendor.rb' I get:

```
Uninitialized constant Vendor::RedCloth
```

Here's my gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.3'


gem "compass", ">= 0.10.6"

gem "haml"
gem 'formtastic'

gem 'devise', :git => 'git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git',  :branch => 'master'
gem 'oa-oauth', :require => "omniauth/oauth"
gem 'mogli'
gem 'dalli'
gem 'exceptional'
gem 'json'
gem 'RedCloth'

group :test, :development do
  gem "ruby-debug19"
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.4"
  gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
  gem 'hpricot'
  gem 'ruby_parser'
  gem 'heroku'
  gem "flutie"
end

group :test do
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'mocha'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'shoulda'
  gem 'ZenTest'
  gem 'fakeweb'
end
```

And here's my model:

```
class Vendor  ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_presence_of :description

  before_save :convert_text

  def convert_text
    self.description = RedCloth.new(self.description).to_html unless self.description.nil?
    self.services_description = RedCloth.new(self.services_description).to_html unless self.services_description.nil?
    self.clients_description = RedCloth.new(self.clients_description).to_html unless self.clients_description.nil?
    self.pricing_description = RedCloth.new(self.pricing_description).to_html unless self.pricing_description.nil?
    self.press = RedCloth.new(self.press).to_html unless self.press.nil?
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be related to the problem I had this morning with RedCloth.

I also installed version 4.2.6 of RedCloth, and then could not use it in a Sinatra app, no matter what I did. (I got a lot of similar errors, `Uninitialized constant RedCloth`.) However, the RedCloth site (http://redcloth.org/) says the latest stable version is only 4.2.2.

I uninstalled 4.2.6 and installed 4.2.2, and it worked perfectly.

Try adding the restriction to your Gemfile, i.e. `gem 'RedCloth', '4.2.2'`

Comment: Great, that was fast!  Works fine now.  Odd that RedCloth would push out a unstable version.  Thanks!

Comment: @Tim: I'm glad it helped! It looks like a ticket for the issue has already been filed (on OSX, but the same issue) here http://jgarber.lighthouseapp.com/projects/13054/tickets/210 so hopefully it'll get fixed soon.